# Javascript : How to log function parameter at exception time

Tags: javascript, debugging, exception, logging

I have a few function in my application in javascript

```
function( param1, param2 )
{

}
```

Sometimes I have caught exception and sometimes uncaught exception

My question is that: Is it possible to log out the parameters at the time of exception **without explicitly** writing error handling code in each function?

```
function(param1, param2)
{
try { /* Big try block contains all code */  } catch(e) { logger.log( param1 , param2) }
}
```

If there is anything like hooking in exceptions and print out the original parameter, that would be great !

Comment: `arguments` is an Array-like object accessible inside functions that contains the values of the arguments passed to that function.

Comment: Thanks @Bikki. That leaves only the question of how to hook on exceptions and print the args out

Answer (score 1):

> without explicitly writing error handling code in each function?

You can create a higher order function for that.

```js
function printErrors(functionToWrap) {
  return function(...args) {
    try {
      functionToWrap(...args)
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      console.log('all passed parameters');
      args.forEach((e) => console.log(e))
    }
  }
}

function logHello(firstName, lastName) { console.log(`hello ${firstName} ${lastName}`) }

function logHelloError(firstName, lastName) { console.xyz(`hello ${firstName} ${lastName}`) }

printErrors(logHello)('John', 'Doe');
printErrors(logHelloError)('Mick','Jones');
```